# How to read an excel file once and keep the results persistently

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to read an excel file with pandas and save it as a dataframe.

However, I do not want to have to read the file every time I run the script. So after the first read, how can I take that value and manually set it equal to some variable to use whenever I need that data?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Do you just mean `df = pd.read_excel(...)`? Then your dataframe can be accessed as `df`.

Comment: I want to that once and them somehow hardcode whatever the value of df is so that I can remove the excel reading part and directly access the data when I run the script later